# jquery select next tbody all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syh9j5x7/)

```html
  <table class="js-table-sections js-table-checkable table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 70px;">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary remove-margin-t remove-margin-b">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" name="check-all"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th style="width: 15%;">Access</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 15%;">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Jhon Smith</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 17, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $28,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 14, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $54,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 6, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $86,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 8, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $86,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 1, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Donald Barnes</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-primary">Personal</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 22, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $32,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 20, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $87,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 18, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $28,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 21, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $29,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 11, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Susan Elliott</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-warning">Trial</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 6, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $41,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 26, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $20,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 23, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $74,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 14, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $40,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 12, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Amy Hunter</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-success">VIP</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 22, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $32,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 11, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $37,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 3, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $66,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 4, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $76,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 2, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

The table has multiple tbody. One tbody is the header and next tbody contains the data rows. The header tbody has a class: js-table-sections-header. How can I check all the rows from the tbody which is under the header tbody using jquery?

Like in the image bellow:

[image]

The header tbody contains the name like: Jhon Smith, etc. When i click the check box from that row I want all other rows from under that to be checked.

Comment: Taking a wild guess, you'd have to loop through all table headers until you find something that matches the one you've ticked, and then loop through the table header after it to tick them all, and finally break the main loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the results with this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[class*="select-all"]').change(function () {
        var this_tbody = $(this).closest('tbody');

        $(this_tbody).next().find('input').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });

    $('#check-all').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('input').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Remember to set the class of the checkbox for the names (Donald Barnes, etc) to `class="select-all"`.

Comment: I don't need to select all rows the global selection is indeed on top table header. As you can see in the image when I select the check box on the row where is the person name Jhon Smith, all rows under that should be checked only, not all rows in the table.

Comment: There is a case for both, when check the checkbox in the header, it checks all checkboxes, when check the checkbox for the name, it checks all the checkboxes below the name.

Comment: I think you just want the first change event in my code, give it a try, just don't forget to set the checkboxes for the names to class="select-all", it will select all the rows under the name.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

You should try this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $("#check-all").on('click', function(e) {

    var bool_check = false;
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     bool_check = true;
    } else {
     bool_check = false;
    }
    
    var checkboxes_list = $("tbody input[type='checkbox']");
   
    //var checkboxes_list = total_inputs.find("tbody:first-child tr label.css-input input");
    checkboxes_list.each(function(i) {
     if(bool_check) {
       $(this).prop('checked', true);
      } else {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
    
    
  });
 
  $(".js-table-sections-header td label input").on('click', function(e) {
   
    var bool_check = false;
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     bool_check = true;
    } else {
     bool_check = false;
    }
    
    var checkboxes_list = $(this).closest('tbody').next().find("input");
   
    //var checkboxes_list = total_inputs.find("tbody:first-child tr label.css-input input");
    checkboxes_list.each(function(i) {
     if(bool_check) {
       $(this).prop('checked', true);
      } else {
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
    
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="js-table-sections js-table-checkable table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 70px;">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary remove-margin-t remove-margin-b">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" name="check-all"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th style="width: 15%;">Access</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 15%;">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Jhon Smith</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 17, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $28,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 14, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $54,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 6, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $86,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 8, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $86,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 1, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Donald Barnes</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-primary">Personal</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 22, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $32,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 20, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $87,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 18, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $28,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 21, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $29,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 11, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Susan Elliott</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-warning">Trial</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 6, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $41,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 26, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $20,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 23, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $74,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 14, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $40,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 12, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </td>
                <td class="font-w600">Amy Hunter</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="label label-success">VIP</span>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <em class="text-muted">June 22, 2015 12:16</em>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $32,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 11, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $37,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 3, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $66,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 4, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <label class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="row_2" name="row_2"><span></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
                <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $76,00</td>
                <td>
                    <small>Paypal</small>
                </td>
                <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <small class="text-muted">June 2, 2015 12:16</small>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just need to select only the rows under Jhon Smith row not all the rows in the table....